# Why does spark read data from source even after data-frame is cached once read from source?

Tags: apache-spark, caching, pyspark

I am reading a data from cassandra table and my after read step I have cached data frame and then I have run count() operation on cached data-frame with assumption that count will make data load into memory. Once data is loaded into spark for next subsequent operations I do not want to again read source but it seems to be happening .
Below are steps:

**step -1 : data read from cassandra:**

```
cassandra_data = read_data_cassandra(spark, c_keyspace, table_name)
cassandra_data.cache()
cassandra_data.count()
```

**STEP-2 : add a column in the data-frame with md5 column**

```
data_wth_hash = prepare_data_md5(cassandra_data)
```

**STEP-3: writing data into s3:**

```
write_full_s3(data_wth_hash, full_data_path)
```

in step -3 my expectation is spark should not refer data , but it seems to be happening as while writing data into s3 program is failing with error "Cassandra readtime failure exception".

Comment: does `prepare_data_md5` contain an action? Otherwise the execution of the DAG is triggered for the first time (and the cache is populated) when you write into S3

Comment: but I have already run count() on cassandra data , count() is also an action .

Comment: from my experience, `count` tries to skip some columns if possible and does not read the whole table. Could you replace count with another action and retry?

Comment: Try running `df.first()` instead of the count. Or after it.